# Is there a way to override the value of spring.profiles.active from application.properties file?

Tags: spring, gradle

I have set the default profile in application.properties file like this:

```
spring.profiles.active=production
```

But I want to have the possibility to change production profile with another one (test or development) by using the following command:

```
gradle -Pspring.profiles.active=production bootRun
```

For the moment, the *production* profile is always loaded (the one set in application.properties file). I read that it is not possible, but I think that there must be a workaround for this... Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### You can follow [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592):

> I ended up doing the following:
>
> ```
> run {
>   systemProperties = System.properties
> }
> ```
>
> Now the command
>
> ```
> gradle bootRun -Dspring.config.location=/somewhere/application.properties
> ```
>
> works.

#### Or, you may also use an environment variable:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test gradle bootRun
```

Sources:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/832
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592

Comment: Thanks for your replay but it didn't work for me. Instead of it, I found another workaround:      project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dspring.profiles.active=${project.gradle.startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs['spring.profiles.active']}"]
}

Comment: Ok! Could you post answer with your solution ?

Comment: I was editing my first comment in order to add the solution while you was writing the comment... Now, it is available. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bootRun { systemProperties['spring.profiles.active']=project.gradle.st‌​artParameter.systemP‌​ropertiesArgs['sprin‌​g.profiles.active']; }
```

also worked for me. In the first solution, if you don't give in the command line one of the defined profiles, the bootRun task fails. But in the second one, it loads the profile from the application.properties. So, I will use the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an environment variable for this.
On Mac this can be done like this

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
```

After you've done this, you should be able to run your application. I've tried this myself using gradle and it works perfectly using `gradle bootRun`